# What is the best way to implement a mongo db search that handles misspelled words?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, soundex

For example I want "wolrd" to return documents with "world" .

Answer (score 2):

You might look at using an external library that has that functionality, [Fuse.js](http://fusejs.io/) is one that looks like it does what you want, as long as you can turn everything you want to search into an array and search through that.

You could also use a [spell-checking library](https://www.javascriptspellcheck.com/) to catch the mis-spelling before you do the search.